# 640x360(360p) Camera resolution

Tags: android, android-camera2, webrtc-android

In my Android app, I would like to use 16:9 resolution for camera preview & transmit via WebRTC call
Wanted to go with 360p (640x360) since its common & it wont require high bitrate to transmit

I am using Camera2 API. As a best practice, I first identified the list of supported resolution on the device to check if 360p is supported or not. Once verified, I proceed to create cameraCapturesession

But this check is failing in some devices - Real Me 5 Pro, Redmi Note 7S, redmi note 7 (all running android versions >=9)
Though it seems to be a popular resolution, 360p is not available in the list of supported resolutions in these devices

List is fetched via cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)
It was not available with getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG) as well

And When I force to create the cameraCaptureSession with 640*360 without verifying supported resolution, It actually worked - it was able to capture 640x360 resolution. Looks like device camera actually supported it, but not available in the list fetched from cameraCharacteristics.

I assume i cannot force this resolution without doing check - as it might not work in some device and will throw exception/crash
I thought of adding a fallback by choosing closest match for 360p - either 16:9 will have to be compromised or 1280x720 will have to be chosen - it ll require higher bitrate to transmit

I think 360p is a std resolution- Any possible reason why it is not listed as supported, but actually worked when forced?
As per my understanding of doc, SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP should return exhaustive list of resolutions supported by hardware
Am I missing anything? Please suggest solution or workaround

Answer (score 0):

16:9 at 640x360 is not really used much on modern mobile cameras, because it's such a low resolution.  720p is about the lowest size people want to record video at, so that gets reflected in the sizes supported.

However, 640x480 (4:3 VGA) is guaranteed to be supported, so the safe thing is to use that and crop if you want to get 16:9.

Assuming the size will work if it's not listed is very risky - it might, or might be stretched, or it might work but if you add some other output it might fall over. And all of this is going to be device-specific, so you just won't know ahead of time, and some new device may just fail.  So I don't recommend it at all.